# In a Safari extension, how do I validate that the open page is a file of a certain format?

Tags: javascript, html, safari-extension

I am new to HTML/JS and I'm making a Safari extension for the first time. I want to enable my toolbar button only when the current page has a .gif open. How do I write my validate function for this?

Also, is the "validate" event fired every time the page reloads? Are there other triggers for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be sure that the content of the current page is a GIF, but you can check whether the URL of the current tab ends with ".gif". In a global page script, use `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url` to get the current URL.

In addition, you can use an injected script to inspect the DOM of the page. In Safari, if a document's body has a single node, and that node is an `<img>`, then the resource located at the tab's URL is probably an image. Use `document.body.childNodes` to check the body contents.

Validate events happen whenever Safari thinks you might want to update an extension element (like a toolbar button). This includes when a tab is opened, closed, focused, or blurred; when its URL is changed; and when its contents are reloaded. BTW, tab focus and blur happens also when Safari itself is focused or blurred, not just when you switch tabs.